# Dual root datum and representation category

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Suppose $G$ is the connected reductive group over a field $k$ corresponding to the root datum $(X^*, \Delta, X_*, \Delta^v)$.

Let $G^v$ be the connected reductive group over $k$ corresponding to the dual root datum $(X_*, \Delta^v, X^*, \Delta)$. (Note that this is not the usual Langlands dual group unless $k = \mathbb{C}$.)

How are the categories of *finite-dimensional* complex representations of $G$ and $G^v$ related? In other words what does dualizing the root datum do to the structure of the representation category? Is there a canonical functor between the symmetric monoidal categories Rep($G$) and Rep($G^v$) that encodes it in general?

Comment: What do you mean by *the* connected reductive $k$-group corresponding to a root datum? Do you mean the *split* reductive $k$-group corresponding to a root datum?

Comment: What do you mean by complex representations of $G$ if $G$ is an algebraic group over a field other than $\mathbb{C}$? (This is clear if $k \subset \mathbb{C}$, but then you may as well assume $k = \mathbb{C}$ to start with.)

Comment: Thanks for the corrections! I've edited the question.

Comment: You don’t seem to have edited the question …